# Creating shortcuts at desired location in Install4j Installer

Tags: install4j, shortcut-file

I need to create shortcuts at any desired location which could be chosen during installation time. Please advise how we can achieve this.

Also during unattended mode installation I want to provide the shortcut location through response var file. Please advise in this case too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Create start menu entry" action with an absolute path.

Set the "Entry name" property to `${installer:shortcutPath}`, then it will take the location from the installer variable "shortcutPath". You can initialize the variable with a "Set a variable" action whose"Register for response file" property is selected.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for the response! I tried by defining Create start menu entry action and set the Entry name as Desktop to set the location as Desktop. It was creating the shortcut in All Programs named Desktop under the default program group of the app.

Comment: I want that user can define the shortcut location in the response.varfile used at the time of invoking the unattended mode installation. The shortcut should be created at the location defined in the properties file. Please advise on this in details.

Comment: I did tell you about the installer variable.

Comment: I added the action create start menu entry and set the entry name as ${installer:shortcutpath}. Just above it I added another action Set a variable and set the variable name as shortcutpath. In the script section I set it with context.getVariable("SHORTCUT_PATH"). Here SHORTCUT_PATH is the variable which I am setting in the response.varfile used by installer during unattended mode installation. I set the SHORTCUT_PATH as Desktop and then run the installer in unattended mode. The shortcut  named as Desktop  was getting created in the Program Group of the application under Start Menu.

Comment: So the value of Entry Name is taken as name of the shortcut not the location although it is set by installer variable. Please suggest

Comment: Hello  Ingo, Please advise where I am making mistake. I need to implement it for my application and it's very crucial for us to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: If the entry name is an absolute path, it will not be placed in the start menu.

Comment: Thank you very much Ingo! It was my bad as I was not using absolute path. It worked in the silent mode. In GUI mode is there any screen we can add to provide user to select the shortcut location while installation. Like in InstallAnywhere it provides a standard screen to create shortcut at user desired location.

Comment: You can use a "Directory selection" screen for that purpose. If you need more flexibility use a "Configurable form" screen with a "Directory chooser" form component.